# Disable slash insertion on TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

Everytime I'm in the math mode and there already is a `\` typed and I type another one, TeXstudio replaces the old one with the new one instead of let me having a `\\` typed. This is annoying me and I would like to disable it, but I can't find where to do it. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? I am using TexStudio and I don't have these problems if I am in math mode (standard settings). Under 'Options/Configue TexStudio' you can usually change these things.

Comment: I have this problem, too. Is there no solution?

Comment: @azureai You can 'remove placeholders' on the backslash by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + K`.